# Execute unit tests in azure pipeline with both a python and a mongo container

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to run unit tests in python, and some of them require a simple Mongo container, in which I insert data.

Here is my actual way of doing that:

```
jobs: 
  - job: BuildMongoComponent
    displayName: Build Mongo Container
    steps:
    - script: |
        # --publish-all because I need a random port
        MONGO_ID=$(docker run --publish-all -d --mount type=bind,source=${PWD}/mongo_mock_data,target=/tmp/mongo_mock_data mongo)
        MONGO_PORT=$( docker inspect $MONGO_ID |  jq -r '.[0].NetworkSettings.Ports."27017/tcp"[0].HostPort' )
        docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --db algo --collection train --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/train_data.json
        docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --db algo --collection calculation --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/predict_data.json --jsonArray
        docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --db pulse_algo --collection cluster --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/cluster_data.json
      env:
        # this value will be lost in the next job. However, I need this value in my Python tests.
        MONGODB_URL: 'mongodb://localhost:${MONGO_PORT}'

  - job: Unittests
    displayName: Unit tests
    container: 'python:3.6'
    steps:
    - script: |
        python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
      displayName: 'Install requirements'
      env:
        PIP_INDEX_URL: $(PIP_INDEX_URL)

    - script: |
        python -m pip install -r requirements.dev.txt
        python -m pytest 
      displayName: 'Unit tests'
      env:
        PIP_INDEX_URL: $(PIP_INDEX_URL)
```

However, it can't work because I can't access the env variable MONGODB_URL outside of this job. I'm not even sure I can access the Mongo Container when I am at the Python job Unittests.

My question: How can I do to
- Build a Mongo Container with a random port, and insert data in it, and then
- Run my python tests and accessing the data in the Mongo container, from my Python container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As design, every agent job is an independent process. So you are facing an expected action.

Without the scenario of mongo container, your issue can be simply understood as how to obtain and access the variable of the `BuildMongoComponent` job in the `Unittests` job.

Since you are using YAML pipeline, here you can set the `MONGODB_URL` as output variable firstly. And then make `Unittests` job [depends on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) `BuildMongoComponent` job.

---

**Sample:**

Simply modified on your script:

```
jobs: 
  - job: BuildMongoComponent
    displayName: Build Mongo Container
    steps:
    - script: |
        # --publish-all because I need a random port
        MONGO_ID=$(docker run --publish-all -d --mount type=bind,source=${PWD}/mongo_mock_data,target=/tmp/mongo_mock_data mongo)
        MONGO_PORT=$( docker inspect $MONGO_ID |  jq -r '.[0].NetworkSettings.Ports."27017/tcp"[0].HostPort' )
        docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --db algo --collection train --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/train_data.json
        docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --db algo --collection calculation --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/predict_data.json --jsonArray
        docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --db pulse_algo --collection cluster --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/cluster_data.json
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PORT;isOutput=true]mongodb://localhost:$MONGO_PORT"
      name: Mongo

  - job: Unittests
    displayName: Unit tests
    container: 'python:3.6'
    dependsOn: BuildMongoComponent
    variables:
      NewPort: $[dependencies.BuildMongoComponent.outputs['Mongo.PORT']]
    steps:
    - script: |
        python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
      displayName: 'Install requirements'
      env:
        PIP_INDEX_URL: $(PIP_INDEX_URL)
```

At this time, you can access the `MONGODB_URL` value in **Unittests** job by using `$(NewPort)` .

---

*Another problem on your script:
Not sure how do you store your PWD value since you did not mention that. If you store it as secret variable, I'm afraid the format you are using is not correct. You should using $(PWD) to get its value.*

Comment: Thank you ! 
An other thing that I needed is the ip adress of the host in order to access the Mongo Container by port mapping. Right now, I am just writing the value 10.4..etc. in my script. But; is there a way to access it using a variable, in my python container?

To summarize: Im in the python container. I want to access the Mongo Container by port mapping using the host ip adress. How to get this ip adress from a variable, without writing it in the script?

Comment: @nolw38, does your ip address is a single value like: 10.14.20.1, or multi-ips?

Comment: I'm not sure, so I do `$(hostname -I | cut -f1 -d' ')` to access the first value (if there are multi ips)

Comment: @nolw38, Here just assume you store the ip(s)  in variable and set is as secret. You can check this doc part to see whether it is help for you:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables. Or you need a script sample?

Comment: You make a specific job out of the containers for that? If you can update the script storing the ip that would be amazing !